# java.lang.IllegalStateException: available processors value [3] did not match current value [1]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am in the process of migrating my plugins to Elastic Search 5.6.8.
Almost all the integeration tests failed with the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: available processors value [3] did not match current value [1]
at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([F28925F4D3226C90:F097ECADD695AF81]:0)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.setAvailableProcessors(Netty4Utils.java:96)
at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.<init>(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:219)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin.lambda$getHttpTransports$1(Netty4Plugin.java:105)
at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:438)
at org.elasticsearch.node.MockNode.<init>(MockNode.java:60)
at org.elasticsearch.test.InternalTestCluster.buildNode(InternalTestCluster.java:602)
at org.elasticsearch.test.InternalTestCluster.buildNode(InternalTestCluster.java:555)
at org.elasticsearch.test.InternalTestCluster.getOrBuildRandomNode(InternalTestCluster.java:461)
at org.elasticsearch.test.InternalTestCluster.client(InternalTestCluster.java:647)
at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.client(ESIntegTestCase.java:636)
at org.elasticsearch.test.ESIntegTestCase.client(ESIntegTestCase.java:629)
at com.trgr.elasticsearch.plugin.maydayalert.MaydayAlertIntegrationTest.waitForClusterToBeInValidState(MaydayAlertIntegrationTest.java:65)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.invoke(RandomizedRunner.java:1713)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$9.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:941)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$10.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:957)
at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
```

elastic website says the following for the issue.
System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false"); 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-5-4-1-availableprocessors-is-already-set/88036/8

However It does not seems to work.
I set the same in almost all the test setup method.

I am not sure whether I am setting in a wrong place.
Is there any other way to fix this problem.

My build.gradle has

elastic group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '5.6.8', transitive: true
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.plugin', name: 'transport-netty4-client', version: '5.6.8'

testCompile group: 'org.elasticsearch.test', name: 'framework', version: '5.6.8'
testCompile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.6'
//testCompile group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna', version: '4.1.0'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: '1.6.1'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.6.1'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-core', version: '1.6.1'